# How to invoke AWS SAM locally using remote docker (as opposed to docker desktop)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, remote-server, invoke, sam

I have AWS SAM installed on a Windows machine. I have followed the instructions here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html to create a test Hello World application.
I have docker server running on a separate (Linux) VM. How do I invoke AWS SAM locally?

I have tried the following:

```
sam local start-api --container-host-interface 0.0.0.0 --container-host 192.168.28.168
```

where `192.168.28.168` is the Linux VM where docker server is running. (I.e. different to the Windows machine I’m developing on).

However, I get “Error: Cannot find module”:

```
PS C:\Develop\AWS\sam-app> sam local start-api --container-host-interface 0.0.0.0 --container-host 192.168.28.168
Mounting HelloWorldFunction at http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello [GET]
You can now browse to the above endpoints to invoke your functions. You do not need to restart/reload SAM CLI while working on your functions, changes will be reflected instantly/automatically. You only need to restart SAM CLI if you update your AWS SAM template
2021-09-24 07:50:10  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Invoking app.lambdaHandler (nodejs14.x)
Skip pulling image and use local one: amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-nodejs14.x:rapid-1.27.2.

Mounting C:\Develop\AWS\sam-app\.aws-sam\build\HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: bd6b8177-56bb-4464-8ead-8c46809e6c6c Version: $LATEST
2021-09-24T06:50:35.674Z        undefined       ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'app'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
time="2021-09-24T06:50:35.691" level=panic msg="ReplyStream not available"
```

SAM is communicating with the container ok, as evidenced by the `START RequestId:…` line. However, it’s failing to find the app.js to run.
I suspect it’s something to do with volume mapping.
I’ve tried setting `--docker-volume-basedir` to various values, but it seems to make no difference.

The “Remote Docker” section on this page https://github.com/thoeni/aws-sam-local#remote-docker suggests that “the project directory must be pre-mounted on the remote host where the Docker is running”. But how do I do that, when I’m not using docker desktop?
There are some similar sounding suggestions here https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2837#issuecomment-879655277 which seem to involve modifying the dockerfile to mount a volume. However, I don’t have a dockerfile – SAM is just pulling the image automatically when invoked.

Any ideas? Is it even possible to invoke AWS Sam locally using a remote docker server as opposed to docker desktop?

The section “Step 3: Install Docker (optional)” of the SAM install guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-windows.html describes setting up shared drives: “The AWS SAM CLI requires that the project directory, or any parent directory, is listed in a shared drive.” However, it’s evident that it’s expecting Docker Desktop, not docker running on a remote server.

Maybe it’s just not possible to invoke AWS SAM locally without Docker Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've now realised where I went wrong.
At this point in the SAM log:

`Mounting C:\Develop\AWS\sam-app\.aws-sam\build\HelloWorldFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container`

AWS SAM is attempting to **bind mount** the `C:\Develop\AWS\...` directory on the Docker **host** to `/var/task` in the Docker container.

My mistake was thinking that it was mounting the actual directory on my local development machine.

I logged into the Docker host machine, and could see the directory structure had been created: `/c/Develop/AWS/...`. I transferred `app.js` from my local development machine to the Docker host's directory, and bingo - it now works. :-)

So, now the description in the AWS SAM developer guide for the `--docker-volume-basedir`makes more sense:

*The location of the base directory where the AWS SAM file exists. If Docker is running on a remote machine, you must mount the path where the AWS SAM file exists on the Docker machine, and modify this value to match the remote machine.*

So I guess I need to create an SMB mapping from the application folder on my Windows development machine to a folder on the Linux Docker host, and ensure that the Docker host (Linux) folder gets used for running the application by setting `--docker-volume-basedir` accordingly.

Comment: msreeves did you manage to debug your function in VSCode using Start Debugging (F5)

Comment: Sorry, not tried this - I've been assigned to another project. :-(